# Refresh and close a plot by detecting key pressed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, event-handling, terminate

I have a simple loop plotting data read from a folder. It loops forever to update the plots and I want to end the program when I press ESC.
So far, I wrote

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axes()

while True:
    ... # loop over data and plot
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)
    plt.cla()
```

If I close the figure by clicking on the X icon the program ends with an error. I can avoid the error by doing

```
    try:
        plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)
    except:
        break
```

But I would still like to be able to terminate the program by pressing ESC on the plot. Also, if I close the plot with CTRL+W the plot reappears.
I tried adding an event detection, like

```
def parse_esc(event):
    if event.key == 'press escape':
        sys.exit(0)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', parse_esc)
```

But it doesn't detect ESC.
I tried with `close_event` instead of `key_press_event` but `sys.exit(0)` gives the following error

```
    while executing
"140506996271368filter_destroy 836 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? 0 ?? ?? .140506996230464 17 ?? ?? ??"
    invoked from within
"if {"[140506996271368filter_destroy 836 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? 0 ?? ?? .140506996230464 17 ?? ?? ??]" == "break"} break"
    (command bound to event)
```

I would also like to remove the loop and refresh the plot only if R is detected, but that's not so important.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone will ever need to do something similar, here is what I did

```
folder = ...

def update():
    plt.cla()
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        if f.endswith(".dat"):
            data = ... 
            plt.plot(data)
    plt.draw()
    print('refreshed')

def handle(event):
    if event.key == 'r':
        update()
    if event.key == 'escape':
        sys.exit(0)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axes()
picsize = fig.get_size_inches() / 1.3
fig.set_size_inches(picsize)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', handle)
update()

input('')
```